# Trying to animate border, logic error I guess?

Tags: javascript, html, animation

The page I am working on is at [keeptheinternetpure.com/memory.html](http://keeptheinternetpure.com/memory.html)

The code is at [keeptheinternetpure.com/myCode.js](http://keeptheinternetpure.com/myCode.js)

The style sheet is at keeptheinternetpure.com/standard.css

I'm trying to get any border of a element with the class "selected" to switch between 2 classes rapidly, effectively making it animated. My code currently works on the left table's cells, but when you start the game and click on the icons to manually change them to the selected class, it doesn't work and has a weird glitch, which leads me to believe that it's an issue with the clickedOn() function. The function that changes the class is borderAnimation(). The borders of selected tiles should look exactly like they do on the left table.

EDIT: here's my clickedOn() function:

```
function clickedOn(index)
{
    tempIndex = index;
    ostream = document.getElementById('coordinates');
    ostream.innerHTML = 'Row ' + (Math.floor(tempIndex / $tblcols) + 1 + ' Column ' + (Math.floor(tempIndex % $tblcols) + 1));  

    //if the user already clicked
    if ($indexCounter >= 2)
        {
            //do nothing
        }
    else if ($theCards[index].status == "unselected")
    {
        $theCards[index].status = "selected";
        displayStatus(index);
        //if the user has guessed 1 time
        if ($selectedCounter < 2)
        {
            //change the status to selected and save the index
            $selectedCounter++;

        if ($selectedCounter != 2)
        {
            $previousIndex = index;
            $indexCounter++;
        }
    }
    //if the user has guessed 2 times
    if ($selectedCounter >= 2)
    {
        //if the types aren't the same
        if ($theCards[$previousIndex].type != $theCards[index].type)
            {
                //change the status back to unselected

                var a = setTimeout(function() {$theCards[index].status = "unselected"; $theCards[$previousIndex].status = "unselected"; displayStatus(index); displayStatus($previousIndex); $indexCounter = 0;}, 1000);
            }
            //if they are the same
            else
            {
                //change the status to solved
                setTimeout(function() {$theCards[$previousIndex].status = "solved"; $theCards[index].status = "solved"; displayStatus($previousIndex); displayStatus(index); $indexCounter = 0; $theScore+=10;}, 500);

                $solved+=2;

            }
            if ($solved == $theCards.length)
            {
                setTimeout(function() {resetGame()}, 1000);
            }

            $selectedCounter =0;

        }
}
```

}

Comment: Could you create a simple example that reproduces the issue and post it here? See [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: You could use a method like this to achieve the border animation, see if it works better: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/animated-photoshop-selection-on-a-web-page

Comment: updated with clickedOn() function...let me know if you need any other functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop backwards, getElementsByClassName is an active [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) so it updates. It is not a static set of found items.

Run this demo:

HTML:

```
<div class="selected">Block</div>
<div class="selected">Block</div>
<div class="selected">Block</div>
<div class="selected">Block</div>
```

CSS:

```
div { border: 1px dashed #CCC; margin: 10px;}

.selected {
    border: 1px dotted #CCC;    
}

.invert {
   background-color: red;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("selected");
for (var i=0;i<elems.length;i++) {
    elems[i].className="invert";
    console.log(elems.length);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ww9WD/

You will get zebra stripes.

Why? Because when you remove the class, the nodeset is updated to reflct the change removing the element and everything after it is shifted down by one to fill in the gap!

Changing the JavaScript to a while loop will fix it

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("selected");
while (elems.length) {
    elems[0].className="invert";
}
```

or a reverse loop

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("selected");
for (var i=elems.length-1i>=0;i--) {
    elems[i].className="invert";        
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by loop backwards...care to elaborate?

Comment: Just like the reverse loop code snipplet I posted. Start at he end, work to zero.